# Symfony2. Simple preauth not working after deploying on hosting, because it try to authenticate one more time after success authentication

Tags: symfony, authentication

In my Symfony application I have two firewalls:

```
main:
    pattern: ^/(?!login).+
    stateless: true
    simple_preauth:
        authenticator: app_bundle.api_key_authenticator
    provider: api_key_user_provider
    anonymous: ~
    logout: ~

login:
    pattern: ^/login$
    stateless: false
    simple_preauth:
        authenticator: app_bundle.email_password_authenticator
    provider: email_user_provider
    anonymous: ~
    logout: ~
```

After authenticating through /login User getting apiKey, which allow get access to another part of app.

On my local server all works fine. But after deploying on hosting authentication not working.

After debugging I see, that email authenticator try to authenticate twice.
So first time it returns correct Token, but second time it returns NULL, because `loadUserByUsername()` method get username instead of email (authentication is possible only through email).

This is my email authenticator:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Security\Authentication;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\SimplePreAuthenticatorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;

class EmailPasswordAuthenticator implements SimplePreAuthenticatorInterface
{
    private $encoder;

    public function __construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)
    {
        $this->encoder = $encoder;
    }

    public function createToken(Request $request, $providerKey)
    {
        if ($request->get('email') && $request->get('password')) {
            return new UsernamePasswordToken(
                $request->get('email'), 
                $request->get('password'), 
                $providerKey
            );
        }

        throw new AuthenticationException('Authentication failed');
    }

    public function authenticateToken(TokenInterface $token, UserProviderInterface $userProvider, $providerKey)
    {
        try {
            $user = $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($token->getUsername());
        } catch (UsernameNotFoundException $e) {
            throw new AuthenticationException('Invalid username or password');
        }

        $passwordValid = $this->encoder->isPasswordValid($user, $token->getCredentials());

        if ($passwordValid) {
            return new UsernamePasswordToken(
                $user,
                $user->getPassword(),
                $providerKey,
                $user->getRoles()
            );
        }

        throw new AuthenticationException('Password incorrect');
    }

    public function supportsToken(TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        return $token instanceof UsernamePasswordToken 
            && $token->getProviderKey() === $providerKey;
    }

}
```

This is my User provider:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Security\User;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class EmailUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct(UserRepository $userRepository)
    {
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    }

    public function loadUserByUsername($email)
    {
        $user = $this->userRepository->findOneBy(array('email' => $email));

        if (null === $user) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
                sprintf(
                    'User with email "%s" not found',
                    $email
                )
            );
        }

        return $user;
    }

    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        return $this->loadUserByUsername($user->getEmail());
    }

    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return $class === 'AppBundle\Entity\User';
    }

}
```

Please, help me to understand, what's going on. What the reason of this weird behavior it can be?

Thanks a lot for any help!

**UPD**. As I can see, `authenticate()` method calls first time by `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\SimplePreAuthenticationListener`, second time - by `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\AccessListener`.

Problem in this part of code:

```
// AccessListener
if (!$token->isAuthenticated()) {
    $token = $this->authManager->authenticate($token);
    $this->tokenStorage->setToken($token);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Problem was in my groups and roles tables, them was empty and without data from them User cannot be authenticated.